# find vertex cover of size at most 30 of a graph

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, time-complexity

This is a question from an exam I got wrong. Given an undirected graph $G$. Consider the decision problem of finding if there exists a vertex cover of size at most 30. Can we find a polynomial time algorithm for this problem? I answered that it is not possible because vertex cover is NP hard, but it turns out that there is a polynomial time algorithm. What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: All problems on vertex cover are not equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be careful about constants! There is a huge difference between the problem
$$
\text{On input } G, n, \text{ does there exist a vertex cover of size at most } n?
$$
and
$$
\text{On input } G, \text{ does there exist a vertex cover of size at most 30}?
$$

Notice, in particular, that the first problem has two inputs, $G$ and $n$. The second problem only has one input, $G$.

The first problem is NP-hard because it is very hard to find vertex covers. But the second problem should look intuitively much easier (when put in this form, where you see that $n$ is not part of the input) -- because we don't have to look for an arbitrary vertex cover, and instead we only have to look for a vertex cover of size at most 30. How does that help us?

Well, how many vertex covers are there of size at most 30? If $|V|$ is the number of vertices in the graph, then there are at most $|V|^{30}$ vertex covers.
That's a big number, but $30$ is a constant -- so it's a **polynomial** in $|V|$ -- that is, it's polynomially many vertex covers that we have to check.

Therefore, this problem is in $P$, and the algorithm is as follows: check all lists of $30$ vertices -- of these lists there are only polynomially many, and they can be enumerated explicitly. For each of these $|V|^{30}$ lists, check if the list is a vertex cover (take a moment to think about how we would check that a given list is a vertex cover or not). Then finally, if any of them *is* a vertex cover, accept; otherwise, if *none* of them is a vertex cover, reject.